# Sharing camera frames between threads

Tags: multithreading, opencv, python-multithreading

I'm trying to build a script to manage multiple threads that are supposed to be running in  parallel, and exchange data between them.
As a starting point, I have two threads...the first one should be reading frames from a USB camera and send them to  queue, while the second should read them and display them.

I tried:

```py
import json
import queue, threading
from queue import Queue
import cv2


class system_manager():
    def __init__(self, source):

        ## camera reader
        self.camera_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.camera_reader = threading.Thread(target=camera_reader, args=(source, self.camera_queue))
        self.camera_reader.daemon = True
        self.camera_reader.run()

        self.camera_display = threading.Thread(target=camera_display, args=(self.camera_queue))
        self.camera_display.daemon = True
        self.camera_display.run()


def camera_reader(source, camera_queue):
    print("Cam Loading...")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
    print("Cam Loaded...")
    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        camera_queue.put(frame)


def camera_display(camera_queue):
    print("doing something")
    while(True):
        frame = camera_queue.get()
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if (key == ord('q')):
            break
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    SM = system_manager(source=0)
```

but it's not really working. The first thread, the one supposed to read frames, is actually doing that, but the second one is not displaying anything (there's a print statement at the beginning, and it's not shown). Also, after running for a few minutes, it got my computer completely stuck, so I assume I'm accidentally continuously occupying memory.
I'm fairly new to multiprocessing/multithreading, so I'm probably doing some very basic mistake somewhere.

EDIT
Ok, fixed the memory problem by using:

```
self.camera_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=5)
```

but the second thread is not working yet

Comment: Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64167273/14119218)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use thread.start() instead of thread.run() , fix the thread target method and add comma after the argument. This works.

```
import json
import queue, threading
from queue import Queue
import cv2


class system_manager():
    def __init__(self, source):

        ## camera reader
        self.camera_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=5)
        self.camera_reader = threading.Thread(target=camera_reader, args=(source, self.camera_queue))
        self.camera_reader.daemon = True
        self.camera_reader.start()
        self.camera_display = threading.Thread(target=camera_display, args=(self.camera_queue,))
        self.camera_display.daemon = True
        self.camera_display.start()


def camera_reader(source, camera_queue):
    print("Cam Loading...")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
    print("Cam Loaded...")
    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        camera_queue.put(frame)


def camera_display(camera_queue):
    print("doing something")
    while(True):
        frame = camera_queue.get()
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if (key == ord('q')):
            break
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    SM = system_manager(source=0)
```